# What does it mean for a point to be "inside" a plane curve?

Tags: graphing-functions, algebraic-curves

Suppose that we have a simple closed curve in the $xy$-plane: $f(x,y)=0$ (for example, $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 4$. If I give you the point $(x,y)$, is there an analytical method to determine whether $(x,y)$ is "inside" $f$? (besides looking at a graph, etc.)

That raises the following question: what exactly does it mean to be "in" a curve? The closest definition my friends and I achieved involved a new space where the line integral of the curve from a given point to a second point is mapped to the distance from that second point to $(x,y)$.

Of course, I feel like this must have been solved a long time ago, and my explanation was rather naïve. Still, I'm having a hard time navigating Wikipedia and the such (MRH).

**What does it mean to be *inside* a simple closed curve?**

Comment: for this simple one if $f(x_0,y_0)$ is negative then the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is inside the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) will be $1$ inside a simple closed curve and zero outside.

If you have a well-behaved simple closed curve imagine a line (ray i.e. one direction) from your point to infinity. If the line crosses the curve an odd number of times the point is inside the curve.

For polygons see, for example, [this link](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html) which deals with both ideas.

Comment: Might the curve be not regular enough for the integral to be defined?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your simple closed curve is the zero set of a function
$$ C: f(x,y) = 0$$
and $f$ also takes positive and negative values. (thanks @Federico Poloni for drawing attention to the need of this last condition).

Now the complement of the curve has two connected components by Jordan's theorem so none of these components can intersects both of the non-void sets $\{f<0\}$ and $\{f>0\}$. It follows that the components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash C$ are  $\{f<0\}$  and $\{f>0\}$. Now you have to figure out what is the bounded component (the inside). Look at the sign of $f$ for large values of $(x,y)$ ( at infinity). The inside is the region of opposite sign.

Inside means not with the infinite.

Comment: Try with the closed curve $\{(x,y) \mid (x^2+y^2-4)^2=0\}$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Thanks, good point! I edited the answer accordingly. Btw, do you have a polynomial example which is not a square?

Comment: Take the previous example and multiply it by $(x-2)^2+y^2$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Square free?

Comment: Can't come up with any at the moment. However, polynomials are only a small and very well-behaved subset of the functions that one might want to consider.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Ah, yes, true. In principle for any closed simple curve  we can find an $f$ continuous ( by Schoenflies' Thm), or even smooth if the curve is smooth. Btw, I wonder  if $0$  is a regular value for the polynomial $f$ , can we tell that the compact(assume that) $f=0$ is connected in an efficient way?